# How To Close A Certain Web Page With Command Line

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, cmd.exe

How do I close a certain web page (in Chrome) with the command line?  I have tried `taskkill /f /im (PID)`.  Also, I am looking for a way to do this without killing the entire Chrome process, e.g. my extensions and apps.  I have searched this on the web but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this question!  It didn't come up in the search results.

Answer (score -1):

you could use autohotkey (a macro editor) to create a macro to do as such, the macro would accept a key combo generated by whatever language you are useing. there is always a way to automate. what, i might ask, are you trying to close from? an executable? useing a script? from command line is not exactly clear as command line is availiable to much.